# Cannot convert `UnityEngine.AudioSource' expression to type `UnityEngine.AudioClip'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making my first game and I have some trouble with my sound scripting. What i want to do is, when the GameObject "key" is active in the hierarchy i want the sound to play once. here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class keyUnlock : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject key;
    public AudioSource clip;

    int keySoundsTotalCount = 1;
    int keySoundsPlayed = 0;

    public void KeyUnlocks () 
    {
        if (key.activeInHierarchy == true) 
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (clip, transform.position); // <---here
            keySoundsPlayed++;
        }
    }
}
```

so in UnityEngine i get these two errors:

```
Assets/Scripts/keyUnlock.cs(17,16): error CS1502: The best overloaded      method match for   `UnityEngine.AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(UnityEngine.AudioClip, UnityEngine.Vector3)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/Scripts/keyUnlock.cs(17,33): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `UnityEngine.AudioSource' expression to type `UnityEngine.AudioClip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html) is the `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint` function blueprint:

```
public static void PlayClipAtPoint(AudioClip clip, Vector3 position, float volume = 1.0F);
```

You are currently passing the `AudioSource` to the clip parameter which expects `AudioClip`.

Simply change `public AudioSource clip;` to `public AudioClip clip;`.